# How to split recipient name and email address using regular expressions in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string array which contains email recipients' names and emails. To send the relevant emails I need to split the values using regular expression. I'm new to this regex area:

Here is the string array

```
[ 
 "Jason D Silva <ejd@yopmail.com>",
 "Aruna Nishantha <arunan@yopmail.com>",
 "Dan Carter <dancarter@yopmail.com>"
]
```

I want to split values into Name and Email. Once the split is done correctly i'm going to insert that to a list as follows:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> recipientList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
  foreach (var item in recipients)
    {
        // Regex pattern 
        if (true)
         {
             //add to recipientList
         }
     }
```

Any help for regex pattern pls?

Comment: did you want `<>` chars in the output?

Comment: @Avinash No.. I don't need. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use following regular expression:

```
^(?<Name>.*)\s\<(?<Email>.*)\>$
```

With this you can retrieve the name and the e-mail address with:

```
var match = Regex.Match("Jason D Silva <ejd@yopmail.com>", @"^(?<Name>.*)\s\<(?<Email>.*)\>$");
var email = match.Groups["Email"].Value;
var name = match.Groups["Name"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

A proper implementation with `String.Substring` method

```
int start, end;

String[] a = {"Jason D Silva <ejd@yopmail.com>","Aruna Nishantha <arunan@yopmail.com>","Dan Carter <dancarter@yopmail.com>" };

 foreach (String item in a)
 {
       Console.WriteLine(item);

       end = item.IndexOf('<');

       Console.WriteLine(" \t Name : " + item.Substring(0, end));

       start = item.IndexOf('<');
       end = item.IndexOf('>');

       Console.WriteLine(" \t email : " + item.Substring(start + 1, end - (start + 1)));

}
```

Output :

```
"Jason D Silva <ejd@yopmail.com>"                                                                                                                                
         Name : Jason D Silva                                                                                                                                     
         email : ejd@yopmail.com                                                                                                                                  
"Aruna Nishantha <arunan@yopmail.com>"                                                                                                                            
         Name : Aruna Nishantha                                                                                                                                   
         email : arunan@yopmail.com                                                                                                                               
"Dan Carter <dancarter@yopmail.com>"                                                                                                                              
         Name : Dan Carter                                                                                                                                        
         email : dancarter@yopmail.com
```

Comment: This implementation really works. Thanks!!. Bt I was looking for a Regex pattern.. Voted up

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need regex for this, you may just use `String.Split` instead:

```
string[] myArray = // ...
foreach(string kv in myArray) 
{
    string[] values = kv.Split(" <");
    // to eliminate the terminating ("noisy" > at the end
    values[1] = values[1].Substring(0, values[1].IndexOf('>');
}
```

This of course assumes that you strings will always look the same.

Comment: the second array item (email) will contain a noisy `>` at the end.